# Android reading and writing values in array or list without overwriting previous values

Tags: android, arrays, database, sharedpreferences

Am just wondering if there is a way to save data into a text file without being overwritten.

Currently i am using sharedpreferences and it overwrites the data which is okay but coinciding with this, i want somewhere where i can keep record of the value before being overwritten in a list or column form.

So it goes something like this: 60, 65, 70..etc The values are stored one after another without being overwritten. I am thinking of doing this locally in a text file which can be read as well. Would also like to know if this is possible in sharedpreferences.

I am doing this so i can create a stats page or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
File logFile = new File(path + "filename.txt");
try{
   FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(logFile,true); //true for append mode
   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
   osw.write("message");
   osw.flush();
   osw.close();
}catch(IOException e){
}
```

Comment: What should i put in the catch? What bit should i replace in my code?

Comment: U can log exception in the catch phrase or do whatever you like, or just leave it. For replacing, replace from File logFile=......  to the end.

Comment: Okay thanks, ive managed to implement it into my code however my values are coming like this: 10.020.0, how can i put a space between 10.0 and 20.0 so it comes 10.0 20.0

Comment: Also is there a way i can do something similar to this in sharedpreferences?